# Can I turn on a laptop with a brand new clean HDD? What will happen?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I've just installed a brand new hard drive in my Dell Inspiron laptop. As I understand it is absolutely clean, no OS in it, it is just from the box, from the store. My question is, can I turn on my laptop with this clean HDD? What will happen?

I know I can insert a USB with Windows OS, or Ubuntu OS and the OS will try to install itself. But what if I do not insert a USB with an OS and turn on a laptop?

And how should I turn it off? OSes have an option "Shut Down". When there is no OS, there is no option. How to turn off a laptop then?

Comment: Press and Hold the power button until it shuts off.

Answer (score 3):

The boot sequence starts with the bios, and once it has checked out the hardware, it will look for a bootable disk - be it usb, hard disk, cd.

If it doesn't find one, it will simply stop and report there is nothing to boot.

To turn of the laptop, hit the power button.  Before the OS is loaded, the power button works as a normal on off switch.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no OS installed, the laptop will get stuck at a screen saying something like "no operating system found", because nothing is installed that could start up.

A shutdown saves data to the hard disk, then turns off the computer with an ACPI-request. As no programs and no OS is running, there's nothing to save and prepare for exiting. There is also no file system that has to be finalized in existance. Even if there was one, it wouldn't be opened if there is nothing to open the filesystem.

It's safe to turn off by hitting the power switch normally.

Answer (score 1):

There will be an error - No OS found/no bootable image found/depends on your BIOS. Nothing more special ;)
Usually you can turn off the laptop by pushing the power button.

Answer (score 0):

When push on the power button to turn the computer on, starts the BIOS first and check if all required haredware components are ok (RAM, CPU, etc.). Then the BIOS is looking for the next bootable data medium like a HDD (it all depents what boot order you have set in the BIOS) and try to load it.

Normally there should start the software bootloader (the first programm that starts when a medium gets booted) to load the partion with the OS. But in your case where is no bootloader, partions or operating system installed you simply get an error-message like these:

[image]

To turn the computer off, you usually just need to push the Power-button again!

Comment: Regarding your flag on [How recover the Product Key of an installed activated Adobe Acrobat XI Standard](http://superuser.com/questions/1057662/how-recover-the-product-key-of-an-installed-activated-adobe-acrobat-xi-standard) stating that you asked the question on a throwaway account but now need to merge the question into your main account. I have spoken to the Community Moderation team who can handle the request and they would like you to contact them directly using the [Contact Us](http://superuser.com/contact) form and they should be able to get it straightened out for you.

Comment: @Mokubai It's been a while (more than one week) that I send the request via "Contact Us" but I still didn't got any response from the SE Team! How long do I have to wait to get to move the question from the trash account to my main? Plz I would like to know?

Comment: Did you use the "Merge account" contact reason or "Other" (bottom of the list) and explain the situation?  I know they can be busy at times, but I would have expected to hear something by now.  Bear in mind though that using a throwaway account can make it difficult to verify any kind of ownership.

Comment: I've used the “Merge account“ option. And I still didn't got any answers or questions if I am are the true ownership or not! So I only want to know if I'm still at the waiting list of them or if my request just got discard away etc.?

Comment: I would give it another try but this time use the "other" option and explain the situation listing both accounts.  I suspect the merge accounts contact is a mostly automatic system that sends an email to both accounts you list and may not be fully monitored.  I don't have any access to SE systems to see any "queue" so I do not know whether they are going to respond or not.  The best I can really do to help is to delete the question and let you re-ask it using this account.